# Trying to write a variable to a file in Python, and I get UnicodeEncodeError

Tags: python, unicode, beautifulsoup, ascii, codec

I am working on making my CS:GO Match Simulator automatically grab statistics about teams and players. To do that, I need the "text" variable written to a text file. If someone can help me with this, that would be great. Thanks in advance!

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf6' in position 58743: ordinal not in range(128)

```
def find_source(pages):
global page
page = 1
fw = open('source_code'+str(page)+'.txt', 'w')
while page <= pages:
    url = "http://www.hltv.org/?pageid=173&playerid="+str(page)+"&eventid=0&gameid=2"
    sc = requests.get(url)
    global text
    text = sc.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(text)
    #print (text)
    text.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
    for link in soup.findAll('a', {'class': 'tab_selected'}):
        href = "http://www.hltv.org" + link.get('href')
        title = link.string
        #fw.write(title + '\n')
        #fw.write(text)
        #fw.write(href + '\n\n')
    page += 1
fw.close()

find_source(1)
```

Comment: You should fix your indents.

Answer (score 1):

This solves it.

```
text = text.encode('utf-8', 'ignore')
```

Comment: Thank you, I looked everywhere for this!

Comment: NP. Happy to help. Please accept this answer if it helped you. :)